# HTML, CSS - Blank space when resized window

Tags: html, css

Please refer to my site: http://www.vault-x.com

With the window maximized the website appears normal.

When the window is reduced in width you are able to scroll left/right, a blank space appears on the right side of the website and I cannot figure out why?

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Which browser? I don't see a blank space, but maybe I tried with the wrong ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set **minimum-width** it will be work fine

example css

```
        header {
    height: 303px;
    min-width:950px;
    background: url('images/head_bg.jpg') center no-repeat,
                url('images/head_liq_bg.jpg') left top repeat;
                text-align: center;

    }
```